# Excel - Repeat list items multiple times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a list of text in excel like the input below, I would like to repeat each of the list items 3 times, in order, using a formula to achieve the Output below.

I've explored trying to do this using `REPT()` but couldn't get it to work. Any ideas ?

I've made a test google sheet to try it in here :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17E-0Vr3fgJQw-A5HfUdH4jINl00NClbToWa32mqotbY/edit#gid=0

**INPUT**

[image: existing list]

**OUTPUT**

[image: output list]

Comment: I believe VBA is the only way to get that done. It could be a UDF (formula with VBA) or that works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Office 365:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*3,,1,1/3)))
```

NOTE:  In testing, some sequences will cause this to error due to Floating decimal errors.  Please see the answer by Joel on how to deal with this if you are getting the wrong sequences.

[image]

---

In older versions put this in B1:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/3)+1)&""
```

And copy down till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: couldnt get the 1st version to work, but the older versions works great, thansk !

Answer (score 2):

Office365:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*3)/3,0))
```

Older Versions:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,ROUNDUP(ROWS($B$1:B1)/3,0))&""
```

Use this Office365 formula instead of the formula listed above, otherwise, you can get some errors due to rounding issues. For example, if you use 9 repeats instead of 3 and you have 8 items in col A, then the 5th item will repeat 10 times and the 8th will only repeat 8 times.

The first answer's older version didn't cause the same rounding error, but it can cause errors due to not using fixed references ($) if you aren't copying all of column A and/or aren't putting the formula on row 1.  Can change $A$1:$A$10 to A:A if using all of column A and $B$1:B1 to $C$2:C2 if putting this formula in column C with a header row, for instance.  Don't need the &"" at the end if you don't want to force the values to be strings.

Answer (score 2):

Office 365

```
=TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(,3),A1:A3),1)
```

[image]