Create n random lists from initial set of values in Excel
I have a list of items in one column of an Excel worksheet:
| Items|
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
The number of items (rows) in this list can vary. I want to create n random lists with the same elements of the original list, like:



Items
Replicates
Result




A
2
B


B

C


C

A


D

D




A




B




D




C



What is important is that:

This will become a template, so it must be done either with a formula, or with VBA
The "Result" column creates Items*Replicates new rows dynamically, so if I add a new item, the rows in "Result" are adjusted accordingly
The randomization must happen treating the items as "blocks": It cannot be "A A D C B D B C", because the first N items (where N is the total number of items) should be randomized together, and then the following N items.

For now, I have only succeeded in creating one random list from the original one by using:
=SORTBY(FILTER(A2:A100;(A2:A100<>""));RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A100)))
my "Items" column being in the A column of an Excel worksheet, and 100 is a random row number that can be modified.

To randomize the results in "blocks", add the RANDARRAY results to the "block number" as follows:
=LET(
    items; TOCOL(A2:A1000; 1);
    n; B2;
    r; ROWS(items);
    SORTBY(
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(; n); items);; TRUE);
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(; r); SEQUENCE(n))) + RANDARRAY(r * n)
    )
)



Try: =LET(a,TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(,B2),TOCOL(A2:A100,1)),1),SORTBY(a,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(a))))

Or for your locale settings:
=LET(a;TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(;B2);TOCOL(A2:A100;1));1),SORTBY(a;RANDARRAY(COUNTA(a))))
Answer is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77669506

Your answer is working well but it made me realize that I need to add another constrain: the Result column must randomize only within the first N items (N = total number of items), treating them like "blocks", so it cannot be like in your result "C E D D E C", because it must contain all the items for each block.

VStack Random Column Without VSTACK
=LET(data,A2:A16,repeats,B2,
    d,TOCOL(data,1),
    dr,ROWS(d),
    rr,dr*repeats,
    s,SEQUENCE(rr)-1,
    INDEX(d,SORTBY(MOD(s,dr)+1,INT(s/dr)+RANDARRAY(rr))))

Lambda Function e.g. VStackRandCol (Name Manager)
=LAMBDA(data,repeats,LET(
    d,TOCOL(data,1),dr,ROWS(d),rr,dr*repeats,s,SEQUENCE(rr)-1,
    INDEX(d,SORTBY(MOD(s,dr)+1,INT(s/dr)+RANDARRAY(rr)))))

Usage
=VStackRandCol(A2:A16,B2)

Variable-Infested (Study Mode)
=LET(data,A2:A16,repeats,B2,
    d,TOCOL(data,1),
    dr,ROWS(d),
    rr,dr*repeats,
    s,SEQUENCE(rr)-1,
    sm,MOD(s,dr)+1,
    si,INT(s/dr),
    ra,RANDARRAY(rr),
    ri,SORTBY(sm,si+ra),
    r,INDEX(d,ri),
    r)



Nice question, you could use:

Formula in D1:
=LET(x,LAMBDA(f,r,i,n,IF(n,f(f,VSTACK(r,SORTBY(i,RANDARRAY(ROWS(i),1))),i,n-1),r)),DROP(x(x,0,A1:A4,B1),1))

It's basically a recursive LAMBDA() which you would just need to adjust the last two parameters to your liking.
